# xaml ambiguity between error

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How can I fix this litter error. I try  to put bool before position but i get another error.

```
  public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
    TimeSpan position;
    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    public MainPage()

    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        VerifyInternetConnection();
     }

  public TimeSpan position { get; set; }

 private void media_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
  //The error is here ----> "position" 
        position = meTestVideo.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan;
        sliderSeek.Minimum = 0;
        sliderSeek.Maximum = position.TotalSeconds;
    }
```

Comment: Where is meTestVideo defined?  What is the error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `MainPage` class has two members called `position`: a property, and a field. You need to delete or rename one of the two.

As a point of note: the error would actually be a couple of lines above where you indicated (on the line where you declare the property `position`), and would probably read something like "The type 'Mainpage' already contains a definition for 'position'." Reading the error message often helps!